# closability of $n$-th power of paranormal operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

It it well-known, that there exists closable paranormal operator $A$ such that $\overline{A}$ is not paranormal [1] and if $B$ is paranormal then $B^n$ is also paranormal [2].

Is there any example of closable paranormal operator $A$ s.th. for any $n\ge 1$ operator $\overline{A^{n}}$ is not paranormal ?

---

[1] A. Daniluk On the closability of paranormal operators  Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications Volume 376, Issue 1, 1 April 2011

[2] T. Furuta, On the class of paranormal operators, Proc. Japan Acad. 43 (1967)